# Django Wagtail image not showing on post detail page

Tags: django, python-3.x, wagtail

I'm trying to work my way through a wagtail tutorial and i'm facing an issue trying to implement images. The images i upload and add to the blog posts are displayed in the post list page but are not showing up in the post detail page. Could anyone let me know what i'm missing right now and if i need to share any additional info. Thanks!

I'm using wagtail V2.1 and this is my current code:

blog/models.py for the post detail page class:

```
class PostPage(Page):
    body = RichTextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='Post date',default=datetime.datetime.today)
    categories = ParentalManyToManyField('blog.BlogCategory',blank=True)
    tags = ClusterTaggableManager(through='blog.BlogPageTag',blank=True)

    header_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
    )

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        ImageChooserPanel('header_image'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        FieldPanel('categories',widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple),
        FieldPanel('tags'),
    ]

    settings_panels = Page.settings_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
    ]

    @property
    def blog_page(self):
        return self.get_parent().specific

    def get_context(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        context = super(PostPage,self).get_context(request,*args,**kwargs)
        context['blog_page'] = self.blog_page
        return context
```

blog/templates/blog/post_page.html for the post detail page: **The image does not show here**

```
    {% extends "blog/base.html" %}
    {% load wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags wagtailroutablepage_tags %}

    {% block content %}

    <!-- Post Title -->
        <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
        <hr>

    <!-- Post Image -->
        {% if post.header_image %}
            {% image post.header_image original as header_image %}
            <img src="{{ header_image.url }}" class="img-responsive" ></img>
        {% endif %}

        <hr>

<!-- Post Body -->
        {{ page.body|richtext }}
        <hr>

        <p><a href="{{ page.get_parent.url }}">Return to blog</a></p>

    {% endblock %}
```

blog/templates/blog/blog_page.html for the post list page: **The image shows up here**

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% load static wagtailcore_tags wagtailimages_tags blogapp_tags %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>{{ blog_page.title }}</h1>

  <div class="intro">{{ blog_page.description }}</div>

  {% for post in posts %}
  <!-- Post Image -->
  {% if post.header_image %}
      {% image post.header_image original as header_image %}
      <img src="{{ header_image.url }}" class="img-responsive" ></img>
  {% endif %}

  <!-- Post Title -->
    <h2>
      <a href="{% post_date_url post blog_page %}">{{ post.title }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endfor %}



{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, i was using post.Image instead of page.Image in the html page :D